# Visual Studio Typescript jquery browser error: Failed to resolve module specifier

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, razor-pages

I have my Visual Studio project with the following `wwwroot` structure for my TS files.

- wwwroot

  - assets

    - js

      - test.ts

This is my test.ts file:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('jQuery is ready!');
});
```

This is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{

  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "ES6",
    //"strict": true,
    "types": [ "bootstrap", "jquery" ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types", // Default path to search typings.
      "./lib/types" // Directory of typings that located by Libman.
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "../wwwroot/assets/js/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

When building the project I can see the test.js generated successfully.

[image]

Then in my `test.html` file just before the `</body>` element I have the reference to my `test.js` file:

```
  <!-- Vendor JS Files -->
  <script src="~/assets/vendor/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/assets/vendor/quill/quill.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Template Main JS File -->
    <script src="~/assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="~/assets/js/test.js"></script>
```

Once I run the project I can see in my console the following error:

[image]

```
Failed to resolve module specifier "jquery". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

****** UPDATE ******

I tried to import to the absolute path of the client jquery folder like this:

```
import * as $ from '../../lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js';

import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('jQuery is ready!');
});
```

And now the error is gone, but now I'm getting this:

[image]

Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
at test.ts:5:1

Any clue how to solve the above issue?